# Creating an aspect ratio calculator

Tags: javascript, html, css

I’m trying to get this to work without the use of update player size, that can be removed.

How it works is, you put numbers in on the width side and the height is supposed to change instantaneously.

Code: https://jsfiddle.net/xyju2bpn/1/

[image]

Replicating how this works:

I wasn't able to find the javscript code here.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

```html
<td class="player-demo-group-options">
  <div class="player-demo-option-row">
    <label for="aspectRatio">Aspect ratio:</label>
    <select class="kd-button kd-menubutton kd-select player-demo-tooltip-zindex" id="aspectRatio" name="aspectRatio" onchange="setPlayerHeight(document.getElementById('aspectRatio').value, document.getElementById('playerWidth').value); return false;">
              <option value="widescreen">16x9</option>
              <option value="standard">4x3</option>
            </select>
  </div>
  <div class="player-demo-option-row">
    <label for="playerWidth">Dimensions:</label>
    <input id="playerWidth" type="text" class="player-demo-text-input" size="2" value="720" onkeyup="setPlayerHeight(document.getElementById('aspectRatio').value, document.getElementById('playerWidth').value); return false;">&nbsp;x&nbsp;<span id="playerHeight">180</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button
      class="button-blue button" onclick="setPlayerSize(document.getElementById('playerWidth').value, document.getElementById('playerHeight').innerHTML); return false;">Update player size</button>
  </div>
</td>
```

Comment: `setPlayerHeight` is not defined", where is it's javascript

Comment: How would I find it on here? https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo

Comment: @RayeesAC Its not OP own code. Its from the link OP mentioned above. So there is no JS at this stage.

Comment: There is javascript,but I wasn't able to pinpoint where the exact code is on here. https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo I tried viewing "view page source" and couldn't find the code.

Comment: Where is the JS code that you've written? Not the `setPlayerSize` code, which you said we can ignore, but the code to do the calculations?

Comment: The code is somewhere on here: https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo I wasn't able to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this,

**height calculated by** if ratio(**4/3**)

```
  ratio = 3/4;
  document.getElementById('playerHeight').textContent = width *ratio;
```

**height calculated by** if ratio(**16/9**)

```
  ratio = 9/16;
  document.getElementById('playerHeight').textContent = width *ratio;
```

```js
function setPlayer(width, height) {
    var ratio;
    var asratio =  document.getElementById('aspectRatio').value;
    if(asratio == 'standard'){
      ratio = 3/4;
      document.getElementById('playerHeight').textContent = width *ratio;
    }
   else{
      ratio = 9/16;
      document.getElementById('playerHeight').textContent = width * ratio;
    }
}
```

```html
<td class="player-demo-group-options">
  <div class="player-demo-option-row">
    <label for="aspectRatio">Aspect ratio:</label>
    <select class="kd-button kd-menubutton kd-select player-demo-tooltip-zindex" id="aspectRatio" name="aspectRatio" onchange="setPlayer(document.getElementById('playerWidth').value, document.getElementById('playerHeight').textContent)">
              <option value="widescreen">16x9</option>
              <option value="standard">4x3</option>
            </select>
  </div><br>
  <div class="player-demo-option-row">
    <label for="playerWidth">Dimensions:</label>
    <input id="playerWidth" type="text" class="player-demo-text-input" size="2" value="720" oninput="setPlayer(document.getElementById('playerWidth').value, document.getElementById('playerHeight').textContent)">&nbsp;x&nbsp;<span id="playerHeight">405</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button
      class="button-blue button" onclick="setPlayer(document.getElementById('playerWidth').value, document.getElementById('playerHeight').textContent)">Update player size</button>
  </div>
</td>
```